# What is the strongest material transparent to alpha radiation?

Tags: material-science, radiation

Is there a material which is transparent to alpha radiation while being able to hold up under atmospheric pressure on one side and ultra high vacuum on the other? Put simply, what material is thin enough to let charged particles through while being strong enough to withstand large pressures from the surrounding air?

Comment: What do you mean by transparent? Zero probability of interaction? There is a variety of materials which can be made of various thicknesses depending on the energy loss you are willing to tolerate.

Comment: Let's say less than 1 percent. Also, maybe talk about the ratio of transparency to thickness as thickness decreases while keeping in mind that at a certain thickness the material will break under atmospheric pressure.

Comment: You want low atomic mass. Beryllium would be fine (except for the health hazards). Thin mica was used in the early 20th century. Mylar is good to for external beams (not uncommon for ion beam analysis of, e.g., art).

Comment: Sheet mica is used for windows in geigercounters.  It's transparent to alpha particles and it's stiff but highly elastic.  The crystalline structure of mica allows it to be cleaved into very thin sheets.  This paper may have the information you need: http://www.minsocam.org/ammin/AM55/AM55_1633.pdf.

Comment: Note that the internal environment in a Geiger-Muller tube is at roughly 1 atmosphere. There are no "thin to alpha" windows for vacuum that I am aware of.

Comment: What is "ultra-high" here? $10^{-9}\,\rm torr$? Higher or lower?

Comment: Around 10^-7 Pa

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be answered without knowing the area of the atmosphere/vacuum barrier.  Any material is transparent to alpha particles if it is thin enough, and any solid impermeable material can support vacuum against atmospheric pressure if the area is small enough.

As discussed in ["How to calculate planar window's buckling pressure in vacuum chamber wall"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207054/145491), the required thickness of a vacuum window depends on the area and shape of the material.

Traditional "alpha transparent" windows are made from thin [mica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mica) sheets.  For example, one alpha source used by [Geiger and Marsden](https://zenodo.org/record/1430706/files/article.pdf) had a $1.5$ mm diameter window made from "a sheet of mica of 0.62 cm air equivalent."
[Modern pancake Geiger-Muller detectors](https://mirionprodstorage.blob.core.windows.net/prod-20220822/cms4_mirion/files/pdf/spec-sheets/c49256_gm_tubes_spec_sheet.pdf) have mica windows up to almost 5 centimetres in diameter that allow significant transmission of alphas above a few MeV.   The pressure inside a Geiger-Muller detector is not quite a vacuum, instead [being a few tenths of an atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93M%C3%BCller_tube#Principle_of_operation), but only slightly smaller diameters would be needed to support full vacuum.
As noted in [@Joel-Polwin's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/790310/145491), larger area alpha-transparent windows would need to be supported by a grid, which would reduce the overall transparency of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to this, but would it be acceptable to have a thin sheet of material (fairly transparent to alpha particles) supported by a grid of thicker, stronger material?  You'd lose sensitivity proportional to the relative surface areas, but I wouldn't be surprised if something like this could handle a differential pressure of 1 atmosphere.

If you're dealing with a highly-radioactive system, you might end up having to deal with your materials being weakened over time by radiation damage.